# Avoid Duplicate Inserts - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 5 columns. I added a unique index for 2 columns on this table. However whenever there were duplicates, query was stopping with an error.

So, in MySQL I used

```
insert IGNORE 
into TABLENAME1 (COLUMNS) 
SELECT COLUMNS from TABLENAME2
```

and I was able to overcome the duplicate error and insert the other rows.

Can you please help me achieve the same in SQL Server? In other words, what will be a equivalent for IGNORE of mysql for duplicate row skip and inserting other rows?

Comment: What on earth is the point in having a *unique* index that allows rows that *violate* uniqueness? Is having bad data really better than building error handling or better data import processes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no equivalent.
Instead you should left join to the destination table during your insert

```
Insert INTO TARGET
SELECT * FROM SOurce
LEFT JOIN Target 
On ..
WHERE Target.Key IS NULL
```

there are other version using Sub Queries or Exists...

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the unique constraint and create it to with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`..Since you can't alter a unique constraint..i advice below steps

1.drop existing unique constraint
2.create it with below definition

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [uq] ON [dbo].[t1]
(
    [id] ASC,
    [id1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = on, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

if you wan't to have unique key and still insert duplicates,then this is the only option

Comment: Thanks pal, i can use this....Once all the inserts are done, i will have to run the delete statement to remove the duplicates ...Am i Right ?

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5)
SELECT DISTINCT v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
FROM TABLE2
```

May be a simple DISTINCT command can solve your problem
Ciao

Comment: This won't help. If the unique index is on `f1,f2` you will still violate the constraint if you have two rows like `1,2,3,4,5` and `1,2,3,5,4`.